# Running a batch file from SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have the following file placed directly in the C drive on my SQL server:

[image: File]

The job is configured as below

[image: Job[2]]

But when i run the job it just loops and loops. If I run the file manually it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the bat file doesn't ask the user anything and doesn't waits for input, as it must run 100% unattended. What's the .bat code?

Comment: It just loads another exe that opens and ODBC connection - no popups/dialogue boxes etc

"E:\Program Files\Unity\Practice Navigator\PNReadOnly.exe" /silent  /username="*****" /password="****"

Comment: How is the job scheduled or which procedure runs the job?

Comment: At the moment I am just running it manually, just testing.

Comment: Is there a chance that the additional connection is blocked by something else in the job?

Comment: It's just a single step, literally just testing to see if the batch file will run from a job now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I did resolve it by using below command and giving permissions to the .bat file for this user `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT`

`cmd.exe /c E:\tools\test.bat`

[image]